# ¿how to show an specific container just once at day?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I need to show the tipical 'use of cookies' message at the bottom of the page just when some user visits the web, and just show it once at day,I'm trying but my code it's not working properly. here's the code I have so far...

```
<div id="cookie1"> </div>
<button id="botoncookie">Acept</button>





   <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('cookie1').style.bottom = '-50px';
var expiresdate =  5000 ; //1 day

$('#botoncookie').on('click',function(){
var mensaje = document.cookie.split('cookie1=')[1] + expiresdate; 
$('#botoncookie').hide();
$('#cookie1').hide();
});

if(mensaje != null){
 document.getElementById('cookie1').style.display = 'none'; 

}else{
 document.cookie = 'cookie1=visto;path=/';
}
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie with an expiration time of 24*60*60 and whenever a page is loaded, check if the cookie exists, otherwise, display the message.

Comment: that's the idea, sure, but I'd like to do it with local storage because I have more storare space

Answer (score 0):

When your page loads execute the following function. This will check when the cookieMsg was displayed. If already displayed today, no need to display. As a boundary case, for the first time load, it will be null and it will anyway works.

**EDIT**: In the previous snippet i was just comparing the date which included time as well, you need to specifically check for date only.

```
function displayMsg(){
  var today = new Date();

  var lastDisplayedOn = localStorage.getItem('cookieLastDisplayed');
  if(lastDisplayedOn){
    var ld = new Date(lastDisplayedOn)
    if(today.getDate() == ld.getDate() && today.getMonth() == ld.getMonth() && today.getFullYear() == ld.getFullYear()){
        donotDisplay()
    }else{
        displayCookie()
    }
  }else{
        displayCookie()
  }
}
```

Comment: @kukiko11 I have changed the snippet, earlier i was comparing the raw date which included time as well. Please try this one. I have tested that on Chrome.